# borland builder c++ oracle question

Tags: c++, oracle, ado, c++builder

I have a Borland builder c++ 6 application calling Oracle 10g database. Operating over a LAN. When the application in question makes a simple db select e.g.

```
select table_name from  element_tablenames where element_id = 10023842
```

the following is recorded as happening in Oracle (from the performance logs)

```
select table_name 
  from element_tablenames 
 where element_id = 10023842
```

then immediately (and not from C++ source code but perhaps deeper)

```
select table_name, element_tablenames.ROWID 
  from element_tablenames 
 where element_id = 10023842
```

The `select` statement is only called  once in the `TADODbQuery` object, yet two queries are being performed - one to parse and the other adds the `ROWID` for executon.

Over a WAN and many, many queries this is obviously a problem to the user.

Does anyone know why this might be happening, can someone suggest a solution?

Comment: Do you need to be edit the data returned?   The RowID is most likely required because are getting an editable dataset.

Comment: hi, the data just gets read. And to be clear, the second SQL statement is not sent by the C++ code. Only the first one does..i'm assuming the oracle client or somethhing else is making the second SQL call because it aint coming from the c++ source. :)

Comment: I don't know Oracle, but for other databases you can add a "for read only" clause to give it a better hint.

Answer (score 3):

Agree with Robert.

The ROWID uniquely identifies a row in a table so that the returned record can be applied back to the database with any changes (or as a DELETE).

Is there a way to identify a particular column (or set of columns) as a primary key so that it can be used to identify a row without using a ROWID.

Comment: thanks - the data just gets read - thats all. See also my reply to Robert. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly where the RowID is coming from, it could be either the `TAdoQuery` implementation or the `Oracle` Driver.     But I am sure I found the reason.

From the [Oracle docs](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/win.102/b14311/using.htm):

If the database table does not contain a primary key, the ROWID must be selected explicitly when populating DataTable.

So I suspect your Table does not have a primary key, either add one or add the rowid.
Either way this will solve the duplicate query problem.

Since you are concerned about performance.   In general

Using `TAdoQuery` you can set the `CursorType` to optimize different behaviors for performance.    [This article](http://delphi.about.com/od/database/l/aa061201a.htm) covers this from a `TAdoQuery` perspective.   [MSDN also has an article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa266528%28v=VS.60%29.aspx) that covers it from from a general ADO Perspective.   Finally the [specifications from the Oracle Driver](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/win.102/b14311/using.htm) can be useful.

I would recommend setting the Cursor to either as they are the only supported by Oracle

- `ctStatic`  - Bi-directional query produced.
- `ctOpenForwardOnly` - Unidirectional query produced, fastest but can't call `Prior`

You can also play with `CursorLocation` to see how it effects your speed.

Comment: thank you so much for your reply... i have checked and the table  does have a primary key. The row "element_id" is the primary key column. I shall investigate your other suggestions.

Comment: @Buzz I would also try adding the rowid initially to the query then to see if only one query is then executed.

Comment: Hi there, i have found the problem. From the Borland c++ book 22-47 "Preparing queries". "Preparing a query is an optional step that precedes query execution. Preparing a query submits the SQL statement and its parameters, if any, to the data access layer and the database server for parsing, resource allocation, and optimization"....so unless you set the Prepared property to true then the data layer makes two calls to the database and this is the cause of the double call. I did change the type of the cursor to forward only and that sorted out the rowid issue.